# Prove a Function in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is Bounded Below

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through the following problem:

Let $f:\Bbb{R^d} \to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$\lim_{\Vert x \Vert \to \infty}  f(x) = \infty$$ Prove $a \in \Bbb{R^d}$ exists such that $f(x) \ge f(a)$ for all $x$ in $\Bbb{R^d}$

I'm having troubles approaching this problem. I understand how limits apply to multivariable functions but I really cannot even think of how to start answering this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Continuous functions are bounded on compact sets.

Comment: Take a ball large enough so that $f(x)\geq1$ outside of it. As  lzralbu pointed out, on the ball itself it will be bounded below by something, say $m$. Now it is bounded below everywhere by min$(1,m)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n) \to m$ where $m$ is the infimum of $f$ over $\mathbb R$. If $\|x_n\| \to \infty$ we get a contradiction since $m \leq f(0)$ so $m$ cannot be $+\infty$. It now follows that some subsequence of $(x_n)$ is a bounded and hence some subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ is convergent. If the limit of this subsequence is $x$ then we get $f(x)=\lim f(x_{n_k})=m$ so the infimum is attained.